# How does Woocommerce handle subscription billing?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm about to migrate a website from Woocommerce to a new system. It currently uses Stripe. I hopped into stripe to grab the Stripe Subscription ID's of each customer to move their subscription plans to the new web site (totally different CMS) – only to find they aren't there. I was hoping to move these ID's over to the new platform to keep things seamless for customers.

In Stripe, there are no subscriptions set up, so I imagine Woocommerce is running a cron job and handling subscription payments as just standard charges.

If I just delete the Woocommerce plugin, will this halt all future subscription payments? As (as far as I can tell) they don't exist outside the plugin files and database?

Answer (score 0):

[WooCommerce uses cron jobs for processing subscriptions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/faq/#section-21), which is why services like [EasyCron.com](https://www.easycron.com) exist just in case WP Cron doesn't run by itself.

So long as Stripe doesn't follow suit with PayPal and set their own subscriptions internally based upon WooCommerce Subscriptions sending the billing agreement to their API, disabling the Subscriptions plugin should end any further requests for billing.

It would be wise to confirm this with the actual Stripe account their current WC Subscriptions setup is connected to.